# DateFormatString to DateTime Format at GridView did not changed

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview

I have to change string at gridview's column to datetime format.
I've research and found it using DataFormatString property at BoundField and set false in HtmlEncode.
But the value didn't changed to DateTime Format.

this is the code:

```
<asp:gridview ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" HtmlEncode="false" DataField="DateEntered" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ItemStyle-Width="50%"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Interest Rate" HtmlEncode="false" DataField="InterestRate" DataFormatString="{0}%" ItemStyle-Width="50%"></asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
```

the value of date is 6 digit numeric, like 260215 (ddMMyy)
but it shows 260215, not 26-02-2015
I need to display it like 26-02-2015 or 26-Feb-2015

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field type which you want to convert to the `DateFormat` is have to be type of the `DateTime`.

So if you are using class objects to bind to the grid you can alter it's get property to convert it to the `datetime` format using the `TryParseExact` as below

```
    public DateTime DateEnteredToShow {get{return DateTime.ParseExact(DateEntered,"ddMMyyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);}}
```

And then in your `Gridview`,

```
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" HtmlEncode="false" DataField="DateEntered" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" ItemStyle-Width="50%"></asp:BoundField>
```

---

**UPDATE**

From your comment it is clear that you can't add the property the alternate way is use the `public function` with the `ItemTemplate`
so you can change your `gridview` as,

```
 <asp:gridview ID="GridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblDateEntered" Text='<%# FormatDate(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DateEntered").ToString()) %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Interest Rate" HtmlEncode="false" DataField="InterestRate" DataFormatString="{0}%" ItemStyle-Width="50%"></asp:BoundField>
  </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

And in your page you need to add the function called `FormatDate` as

```
 public string FormatDate(string date)
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(date,"ddMMyyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: what is another alternative solution if i can't add property to return datetime? because i am using a library, and the DateEntered field type is return integer

Comment: because the class that use to return the value is in library, and i can't change it. How to parse the value inside RowBound event?